# Android ArrayAdapter working only once

Tags: android, android-listview, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I have a Listview with a custom ArrayAdapter that is set inside of a fragment. Only the first row in the ListView is being set.

This may be a common problem when using ListViews with fragments in general as I've followed the tutorials on custom ArrayAdapters from [here](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/) to the letter (as far as I can tell).

**MyFragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_listview);

    ArrayList<CustomRow> customList = new ArrayList<CustomRow>();
    customList.add(new CustomRow("Test A", "A", "AA");
    customList.add(new CustomRow("Test B", "B", "BB");
    customList.add(new CustomRow("Test C", "C", "CC");

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listitem_custom, customList);
    myListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;

}
```

}

So even though three rows are added to the list, only the first ListItem says "Test A", "A", "AA". The last two rows simply keep the text as defined in the layout (i.e. the text is never actually set to anything, not even null)

**Custom ArrayAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomRowItem> {

Context context;
ArrayList<CustomRowItem> rowList;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CustomRowItem> rowList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, rowList);
    this.context = context;
    this.rowList = rowList;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvText1;
    public TextView tvText2;
    public TextView tvText3;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    // called when listview is not instantiated yet (first run)
    if (convertView == null) {

        // assigns the layout custom_row.xml as the listitem (a single row)
        LayoutInflater alarmInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = alarmInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_custom, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        holder.tvText2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        holder.tvText3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    // called when list view is already instantiated and we are updating the fields
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        CustomRowItem newRow = rowList.get(position);

        if (newRow != null) {

            holder.tvText1.setText(newRow.getText1());
            holder.tvText2.setText(newRow.getText2());
            holder.tvText3.setText(newRow.getText3());

        }

    }


    return convertView;
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the else statement in your `getView()` has more code than it should. this is how it should be:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    // called when listview is not instantiated yet (first run)
    if (convertView == null) {

        // assigns the layout custom_row.xml as the listitem (a single row)
        LayoutInflater alarmInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = alarmInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_custom, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvText1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        holder.tvText2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        holder.tvText3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

        // called when list view is already instantiated and we are updating the fields
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // <-- that's all for here
    }

    CustomRowItem newRow = rowList.get(position);
    if (newRow != null) {
        holder.tvText1.setText(newRow.getText1());
        holder.tvText2.setText(newRow.getText2());
        holder.tvText3.setText(newRow.getText3());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks mango! I didn't even spot that after debugging the application as it appeared to be setting the fields as expected